# toFixed hanging my code

Tags: javascript

I am taking practice exercises and ran into this issue.

This problem asks:

> “Prompt for a number greater than 1 and to 4 decimal places. Format
>   and write the number to the page displaying with only 2 digits past
>   the decimal point using the toFixed() method. (e.g.  12.35, not
>   12.3453)
>
> Since this method is very new, it doesn't work in older browsers. See
>   if you can get only 2 digits past the decimal point to show without
>   using toFixed().”

I found the answer to the hard part through the archives here, Math.round(n*100)/100. Thanks for that. But when I tried the “easy” way, I get nothing. My work is at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QYBHU/), but in a nutshell:

```
var num = prompt("Give me a number greater than one, with 4 decimal places.");
var num2 = prompt("Great! Do one more, please!");


num = Math.round(num*100)/100;
num2 = num2.toFixed(2);


alert(num);
alert(num2);
```

The exercise did not ask for a second number, but I wanted to use both methods in separate incidences. When I run this it does not alert anything. I know that it is hanging at the toFixed statement, because when I comment it out it alerts both as expected, num1 at 2 decimal places, and num2 as it was prompted (i.e. 1.2345).

So here is what I have done so far:

Mozilla’s developer page shows this format: n.toFixed(1);// Returns "12345.7": note rounding

Seems exactly what I am doing.

I copied and pasted all of it in my Sublime, making sure that I called the .js file just before the closing body tag, to make sure it wasn’t some loading problem I don’t understand.

Plus all sorts of little tweaking.

Sorry to keep asking these questions, but since I am self-study, I have where else to go!

Comment: You have a string in num2, you need `parseFloat(num2).toFixed(2);` - press f12 and look in the console at num2 does not have a method toFixed

Comment: Values returned from, well almost anything, are always strings, and the console says "...has no method toFixed" which is a clue that it's not a number!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `parseFloat`. Using the function will convert the string to a float type variable, allowing for the `toFixed` function to work properly.

```
num2 = parseFloat(num2).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: parseFloat will convert the prompted variable from a string to a Float number, which will allow `toFixed` to do its business properly on the variable

Comment: `parseFloat` has no radix argument so this should read `parseFloat(num2)`

Comment: @khanahk I've inserted that little explanation

Comment: GRRRRR! I KNEW that alerts returned strings! Didn't even think about it here, though. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: no problem. you can select this as the answer by using the outlined checkmark under the votes